# Why is SysRq doc not where specified by `man vlock`?

Tags: documentation

`man vlock` says to look in /usr/src/linux/Documentation/sysrq.txt. This file isn't there (though it's available online). Why?

Answer (score 5):

The kernel documentation can be found in the `linux-doc` package.  Once that is installed, you should be able to find the file under `/usr/share/doc/linux-doc`.

The `/usr/src/linux/Documentation` location is a bit of an anachronism.  It used to be common to unpack the Linux kernel source code under `/usr/src/linux`, which would have placed the documentation in the location you mentioned.  However these days most people use the pre-built kernels from their distribution, and even if they do build their own kernel they are likely to do it in their home directory instead.